# How to limit amount of Mongoose Documents displayed?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I created a social network that uses MongoDB to store posts and such. As of now, when the main page is loaded, it shows all those posts in the database. (ShareCookie.com is my site so you can see) It works for now, but once there get to be 1,000+ posts with images, text, html and everything in them, I can imagine it will slow down and could crash my site. What I would like to do is, load maybe only 20 posts, and then add a "load more" button or something at the bottom of the page, which gets the next 20 posts in the database. This is my code as of now to load and send the posts to my home page:

```
Post.find({}, null, { sort: '-created' }, function (err, posts) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        res.render('index', { title: 'ShareCookie', filter: 'date', posts: posts, user: req.user});
});
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: add `limit:20` after your sort to get first 20 documents. Increment and pass limit parameter to your action to load more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `limit:20` after your sort to get first 20 documents. On the client side, increment and pass limit parameter to your action to load more.

Comment: Thanks! Worked beautifully